# Magento 2.3.5 SessionHandler::read():

Tags: magento2.3

my site some time in a day go down and debug show me this error:

```
{"0":"Warning: SessionHandler::read(): The session id is too long or contains illegal characters, valid characters are a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and '-,' in \/var\/www\/vhosts\/xxxx.com\/httpdocs\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Session\/SaveHandler\/Native.php on line 22","1":"#1
```

How can I solve this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3185779/the-session-id-is-too-long-or-contains-illegal-characters-valid-characters-are
Try to check that and try to understand if it's malicious attempts.

This might help too https://www.reddit.com/r/PHP/comments/3n6wc9/session_start_issues_regarding_illegal_characters/

For what I've seen can be a bunch of things causing it but of I understood just make sure it isn't malicious attempts and you don't need to worry that much about it if it isn't,
hope it helps :D

Comment: Hi, but how can I fix it in magento?

Comment: I don't think it has to be with magento, it looks like PHP itself, you might need to add code to the PHP files in the server. I think magento tells you because the session come with the error from PHP and when magento go and read he see it's wrong

Comment: I find a solution in this post on github: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/25142

Comment: That's good, create an answer with that, refer to that link but to the one answer that helped you and accept as resolved, might help someone with the same problem :D